# How To Return Month as Int On Custom Fiscal Year Start

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query which determines the start of the fiscal year I want:

```
DECLARE @StartOfFY int;
SET @StartOfFY = -4; -- September
SELECT DateAdd(mm, @StartOfFY, 
        DateAdd(yy,
            DateDiff(yy,0,
                DateAdd(mm,0,Getdate())
            ),0
         )
        ) 
-- Returns 2019-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

I based the query off on this site: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-handle-calculations-related-to-fiscal-year-and-quarter

The custom start of fiscal year that I want is `September` and I want the query to return an int depending on the fiscal year month.

Ex:
If month is `September` returns 1, for `October` returns 2, and so on until it gets to `September` again to return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract 8 months and return the month:

```
select month(dateadd(month, -8, getdate()))
```

Actually, because the fiscal year is probably for the *next* year, so Sep 2020 is FY 2021, add four months and then year and month work:

```
select month(dateadd(month, 4, getdate())) as fy_month,
       year(dateadd(month, 4, getdate())) as fy_year
```